# Is using 'useEffect' and 'useCallback' a redundancy?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a custom hook in my React app that handles back navigation actions (POP). It's working fine but I think that `useCallback` and `useEffect` are doing exactly the same thing.

Here's my code:

```js
export default function Index(onBackEvent?: () => void) {
  const handleBackPress = useCallback((e: PopStateEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    window.history.pushState(null, '', window.location.pathname)
    if (onBackEvent) onBackEvent()
  }, [onBackEvent])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.history.pushState(null, '', window.location.pathname)
    window.addEventListener('popstate', handleBackPress)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handleBackPress)
    }
  }, [handleBackPress])
}
```

`useEffect` "watches" for `handleBackPress` changes which is `useCallback` "watching" for `onBackEvent` changes.

So my questions are:

- Is this a redundancy?
- If it does, how can I simplify this code?

Comment: For starters: `useCallback` creates a memoized function, while `useEffect` actually executes the function.

Comment: *"Is using 'useEffect' and 'useCallback' a redundancy?"* No. You could call `useCallback` is a special case of `useMemo`, but `useEffect` is a different beast. `useCallback` and `useMemo` deal with memoization while `useEffect` deals with sideeffects and synchronization issues/topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is using 'useEffect' and 'useCallback' a redundancy?

Alone, in isolation? No, not at all. These two hooks exist to serve two completely different purposes.

- `useEffect`

  The `useEffect` hook is to issue *intentional* side-effects from what is otherwise considered to be a pure function that renders UI from JSX.
- `useCallback`

  The `useCallback` hook memoizes a function such that a ***stable*** function reference is passed along, e.g. to a `useEffect` hook, or to children as props, so it doesn't trigger unnecessary rerenders. In other words, it is a performance optimization/optimizer.

Instead of recreating the `handleBackPress` and adding/removing event listeners ***each time*** the `onBackEvent` is changed, I recommend moving `handleBackPress` ***into*** the `useEffect` hook so it can be provided  as a stable callback reference, and to use a React ref to cache the `onBackEvent` callback. Use an empty array for the `useEffect` hook so the listeners are only instantiated once and removed when the component unmounts via the cleanup function.

Example:

```js
export default function useIndex(onBackEvent?: () => void) {
  const onBackEventRef = React.useRef<() => void | undefined>();

  useEffect(() => {
    onBackEventRef.current = onBackEvent;
  }, [onBackEvent]);

  useEffect( () => {
    const handleBackPress = (e: PopStateEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.history.pushState(null, '', window.location.pathname);
      if (onBackEventRef.current) {
        onBackEventRef.current();
      }
    };

    window.history.pushState(null, '', window.location.pathname);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', handleBackPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handleBackPress);
    };
  }, []);
}
```